# How to distribute python module under a specific name

Tags: python, distutils

I have python module, named `models.py` which i would like to upload to PyPi. When afterwards i install it using `pip` i would like it to appear as a package.

To explain myself, I have following project structure:

```
my_utils
  mapper/
    models.py
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
    README
  logger/
    logger.py
    logger_conf.json
    MANIFEST.in
    README
    setup.py
```

I would like to create a distributed package out `mapper.models`, but when it is being installed on target machine, i would like it to appear in `site-packages` under `mapper_tools.models`.

My `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='mapper_tools',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='some description',
    author='myname',
    author_email='my@email.com',
    url='https://github.com/mapper-tools',
    py_modules=['models'],
)
```

My `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include models.py README
```

Currently, after running `pip install mapper-tools`, I find `models.py` right under `site-packages` and I would like it to appear under `mapper_tools`.

Can i specify the structure that should be installed without changing the layout of my project?